# swift-can't present my second scene from GameViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have two scene, GameScene and PlayScene. I am able to present my GameScene, but I can't present PlayScene and I am using the same code and the right file name.I'm using a UIButton to call this function. I even tried not calling showGameScene and only calling goToPlayScene and it still doesn't work.and I'm using GameViewController to present these two scenes.

```
func showGameScene()
{
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
func goToPlayScene()
{
    playButton.hidden = true
    Leaderboard.hidden = true

    if let scene = PlayScene(fileNamed:"PlayScene")
    {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at skView.presentScene(scene) or a print statement after it? Just to ensure that it is in fact getting called

Comment: yes I tried a print, but the statement doesn't get called. and if I don't use the if statement and force warp it, it gives me nil.

Comment: Wait, so if you just put a print statement after skView.presentScene(scene) and leave everything else as is, the print statement doesn't get called?

Comment: This would suggest that your program isn't evaluating the condition (scene = PlayScene(fileNamed:"PlayScene") as true. Make sure you have a file named PlayScene.

Comment: Okay, MailE's answer should point you in the right direction then

Comment: yes its not evaluating it because its returning nil, and I do have the correct file name.

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately we've reached the extent of my knowledge. I'm pretty new to iOS. Try to find out why it is coming as nil. It shouldn't be.

Comment: read my comment for MailE, maybe that will explain it. So I think each scene has its own scene.sks (SpriteKit Scene ) unless you are using SKTransition which will use the previous .sks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created file PlayScene.sks?

Comment: Okay great it worked! :) and before I was using GameScene.swift to transit to PlayScene.swift and it worked and i'm guessing it worked because it was using GameScene.sks for PlayScene.swift right ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I have just created test file in Xcode.

Comment: Yes,  the file named is looking for the sks file. So if you did `PlayScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")` you would get a PlayScene instance with a GameScene sks design.  If you are not doing anything with the sks files,  then they are not even needed, and you can just init it like you would any other object, e.g. `PlayScene()`